# set default value using Kartik selectbox yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Please help... I am trying to set default value for this: I know it is based on Kartik select on yii2. I didn't use it before. Here is my source code I would need to set default value based on $_GET parameters. But problem is I can't set any. The source is this...

```
<?php
     echo $form->field($profile, 'country_id')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
        'language' => Yii::$app->language,
        'data' => ArrayHelper::map($countries, 'id', 'title_' . mb_substr(Yii::$app->language, 0, 2)),
        'theme' => Select2::THEME_BOOTSTRAP,
        'options' => [
            'id' => 'country-select',
            'placeholder' => Yii::t('frontend', 'Select a country')],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'allowClear' => true,
        ],
    ])->label($Country, ['class' => 'label-class']) 
?>
```

Where Should I set it in this case. Sorry, I just saw this plugin at first time...

Comment: Thanks for editing this. But I realy don't know how to use it normally... And plus I didn't write this. I had it already in my project...

Comment: [docs](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2#usage-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you wanna set the default value, you should use the model like the following code;

```
$profile->country_id = isset($profile->country_id) ? $profile->country_id : 1 // like that
```

also you can use in afterFind function on the model.

check this [Yii2: How to set default attribute values in ActiveRecord?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39314213/yii2-how-to-set-default-attribute-values-in-activerecord) and this https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-core-validators#default